# How to use cell range in SQL

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to remove the need to manually look up values, I receive a list with case numbers that need to be matched with IDs.  Right now I am pulling the IDs and adding with a vlookup.
The query I use in SQL is super basic

```
Select Case_Number, ID from Table where Case_Numbber in ();
```

I need to figure out who to run the query inside a macro where it uses the cell range.  So something like this

```
Select Case_Number, ID from Table where Case_Numbber in (Sheet1!A1:A10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do

`"'" & join(application.transpose(worksheets("Sheet1").range("a1:a10").value),"','") & "'"`  for text values

or `join(application.transpose(worksheets("Sheet1").range("a1:a10").value),",")` for numeric